# biblatex package recommends biber (>= 0.9), but it doesn't exist

Tags: 11.10, package-management, latex

I'm not sure I understand what this means. How can Ubuntu recommend something that isn't in the repository? Am I supposed to fetch the source code and install myself? Why isn't there a biber package?

To be clear, I *can* use biblatex without biber, but it preferable to use them together.

Update: OK, I guess I'll download the biber source. I'd rather not install the whole texlive, because it's cumbersome to say the least.

By the way, biber is a terrible package name - when searching for it on Google I keep getting it corrected to Bieber, argh.

Comment: It is clearly a bug, that you should signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can Ubuntu recommend something that isn't in the repository?

I would agree, if it would be a dependency. But a recommendation is not that strong that it breaks something.

Biber is not included, because it is not stable and still experimental.

Here are some links, how to install *vanilla* TeXLive (incl. biber)

[Installing “vanilla” TeXLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
[TeXLive on Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html)
[Installing TeXLive](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/linux/kile-texlive-2008-equivs/)

Ubuntu 12.04 uses biblatex version 1.7-1; you can verify this by running:

`apt-cache show biblatex`

According to [the biber documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/documentation/biber.pdf/download), the last biber release to support biblatex 1.7 is biber 0.9.9.

You can download the appropriate version of biber 0.9.9—32bit or 64bit—here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/0.9.9/binaries/Linux/